# isset() is not working as wishing in php form

Tags: php

I want to access a variable from `$_GET` in a php form but isset is not working as expect to fulfill my request

When I remove the `isset()` function and set an echo it showing the value but I need to validate the value using an `isset()`. I can't find out what's happening

Here is my code:

```
<a href="delete.php?delete=<?php echo $rows ['isbn'] ;?>" class="btn btn-danger ">delete</a>
```

and here is where I access the delete value

```
if (isset($GET['delete'])){
  $id = $_GET['delete'];
  $query="DELETE FROM books WHERE isbn=$id";
  mysqli_query($con,$query);
  header("Location: /Login/welcome.php");
  exit(0); 

 }
```

When I simply echo the `$GET['delete']` value before the `if` clause it prints the value properly, but it doesn't go through the `if` clause

Comment: Im fairly sure you need to put your id variable needs to be in quotes in the query, so '$id' at the end of the statement

Comment: So right it like 

 $query="DELETE FROM books WHERE isbn = '$id' ";

Comment: But make sure you escape that get variable before you input anything in the database, or better yet use pdo and bind it.

Comment: thats not the case @MikeAbineri actually code doesn't execute through the if statement when i put a echo statement outside the if clause it prints properly but not print any when i put an echo statement inside the if clause

Comment: It is `$_GET[]` not `$GET[]`

Comment: how did i miss it :( thanks @Alex

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First, I recommend using POST method on such action (deletion) as with that you will avoid [SQL Injection](https://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection), And your code mistake is on spelling ($_GET inside isset function not $GET)

Comment: POST doesn't prevent SQL injection, it only prevents accidental deletion of records by crawling URLs. To prevent SQL injection you should use prepared statements rather than concatenating queries with the id (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `isset($_GET['delete'])` instead of `isset($GET['delete'])`.

Also, using the `POST` method will prevent accidental deletion of records by web crawlers or users editing URLs

```html
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="<?php echo $rows['isbn'];?>">
   <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

And you should use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to prevent SQL injection attacks (where malicious users can [make your database server to things you don't want it to do](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html))

```php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])){

   $query = $con->prepare('DELETE FROM books WHERE isbn=?');
   $query->bind_param("i", $_POST['delete']); 
   /*
   * the 'i' above assumes your ISBNs are integers and don't 
   * include the '-' character. 
   * see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
   * for more information on the parameter types you can specify
   */
   $query->execute(); 

   header("Location: /Login/welcome.php");
   exit(0); 
}
```

Comment: Bad idea how using the ID in sense of SQL injection.

Comment: POST doesn't prevent SQL injection, it only prevents accidental deletion of records by crawling URLs. To prevent SQL injection you should use prepared statements rather than concatenating queries with the id (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)